# Search through array of strings and check for more than one empty value

Tags: c#, arrays, gridview

I have a grid view (called OptionChoicesGrid) of product option choices with various fields in it, and one of them is a textbox field called "SkuMod." Only one option choice may have an empty SkuMod field--the rest must contain a value. I am trying to figure out the best way to use an array to perform this check since one empty field can be allowed. Or maybe I shouldn't use an array? Any suggestions would be great!

This is a function I'm building right now:

```
protected bool CheckSkuMod()
{
    bool ValidMods = true;
    OptionChoice opt; //opt.SkuModifier is used to check that particular choice 


    foreach (GridViewRow row in OptionChoicesGrid.Rows)
    {

        //build array here?
    }
    return ValidMods;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `int countEmpty = yourList.Count(item => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.SomeStringProperty));`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(OptionChoicesGrid.Rows.Count(r => string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.field) > 1){
     validMods = false;
}
```